# Use :not selector to exclude a div and all its descendants

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a situation where a style of purple font color with a light yellow background needs to be applied to all divs outside a div having a class of `RadDiv`.

This means all divs that are nested within the div with class of `RadDiv` should be excluded.

I tried using `:not` selector as shown below but it does not work. [Demo of my situation](http://js.do/sun21170/77657)

**Question**: How would I specify the `:not` selector to exclude a div with a class of `RadDiv` and all nested divs inside this div?

**:not selector that does not work**

```
div:not(.RadDiv) div   {
  background-color:lightyellow;
  color:purple;
  }
```

**Complete code that I tried**

```
<div>This is a div </div>
<div class="RadDiv newDiv outerDiv">
    <div class="header">
      This is the header
    </div>

     This is an outer div

     <div class="alert highlight">
      This div stands out
    </div>
    <div class="footer disclaimer">
     This is the footer part
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
         <div>This is div inside a table element</div>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="div1">This is div1</div>
<div id="div2">This is div2</div>
<style>
div:not(.RadDiv) div   {
  background-color:lightyellow;
  color:purple;
  }
  .outerDiv {
      border:1px solid red;
      font-family:Arial;
  }
  .footer {
    color:lightgray;
    font-size:small;
    font-style:italic;
    }
    .header {
    font-weight:bold;
    }
```

Comment: Try this: `div:not(.RadDiv div)`

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat all divs of the same level as siblings. Therefore, start by selecting the parent:

```
body > div:not(.RadDiv) {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    color: purple;
}
```

Using the child combinator (`>`), only one level is targeted, and the `:not` selector can be used to exclude any sibling (including its descendants).

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r3k93ms6/)

References:

- [6.6.7. The negation pseudo-class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation)
- [8.2. Child Combinators](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#child-combinators)

Comment: That makes sense. `So, the trick is to find the parent of all divs` . Also, if I have  span elements outside the RadDiv then  they would also be styled with purple font, even though I wanted  only divs to be styled with purple font.

Comment: No. The selector in my answer only targets div elements.

Comment: If you have different elements at the same level, and you want them all targeted *except for `RadDiv`*, you could adjust the selector to: `body > *:not(.RadDiv)`

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

:not selector is not so powerful and it doesn't work the way you would like it to in more complicated situations. The easiest way to achieve what you want will probably be to override .RadDiv styles:

```
div {
  background-color:lightyellow;
  color:purple;
  }
.RadDiv, .RadDiv div {
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
}
```